# react how to add event listeners to multiple elements at once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, addeventlistener

To demonstrate my question, I'll compare vanilla javascript and react. In javascript, when I have

```
<div>
<button class="btn">1</button>
<button class="btn">2</button>
<button class="btn">3</button>
<button class="btn">4</button>
<button class="btn">5</button>
</div>
```

and I want to add some functionality to all buttons, I can do

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
buttons.forEach(btn=>{
   btn.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
       //some code here
   })
})
```

In react, how can I do the same thing, instead of adding "onClick" to every single button? Because imagine if there are 20 buttons like this:

```
<button className="btn" onClick={()=>{
   //some code here
}}>button</button>
```

I could still use querySelector like the javascript way, but I heard that is a bad practice in react. So I wonder if there is any other way that can make the code cleaner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React is perfect for this, because it allows you to reuse components! You could make a component that contains your click handler, then reuse it throughout your application.

```js
const MyReusableButton = () => {
  const myClickHandler = () => {
    console.log("Clicked!");
  }
  return <button onClick = {myClickHandler}>Click Me</button>;
}

const App = () => {
  // now I can reuse my button component as many times as I want!
  return (
    <div>
      <MyReusableButton />
      <MyReusableButton />
      <MyReusableButton />
      <MyReusableButton />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: You're still adding a listener for each button. Event delegation is probably the best way to answer the question.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of attaching a listener to each button you can use event delegation to attach one listener to a container to watch for events as they "bubble up" the DOM from each child element/component.

```js
function Example() {

  function handleClick(e) {
    const { nodeName, textContent } = e.target;
    if (nodeName === 'BUTTON') {
      console.log(textContent);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div onClick={handleClick}>
      <button>Click me 1</button>
      <button>Click me 2</button>
      <button>Click me 3</button>
      <button>Click me 4</button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a list that describes whatever is unique about your buttons. Map the list into your buttons.

```js
const nums = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
return <div>
    {nums.map(num => 
        <button onClick={() => console.info("clicked" + num)}>
            This is button {num}     
        </button>
    )}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the best approach for this situation is event delegation we have to attach an event listener to the parent element and handle the event on the children elements.

```
function clickMe(e) {
const btn = e.target.closest(".btn");
if (!btn) return; 
// more code here
}
// the JSX code : 

<div className="test" onClick={clickMe}>
  <button class="btn">1</button> 
  <button class="btn">2</button>
  <button class="btn">3</button>
  <button class="btn">4</button>
  <button class="btn">5</button>
</div>;
```

Answer (score -2):

Use a loop to create an array of JSX objects and render them. This is an example from an earlier project I was working on.

```
  let grid = []
  maze.forEach((row, i) => {
    let renderedRow = []
    row.forEach((block, j) => {
      renderedRow.push(<Block key={size.width * i + j}
        inheritedType={block}
        dimensions={defaultDimensions * scale}
        onAction={() => {
          setBlock(i, j)
          setMazeFuture([])
        }}
        onDoubleClick={() => updateMaze(i, j, "empty")}
        isDown = {isDown}
        setIsDown={setIsDown}
        appendToHistory={appendCurrentMazeToHistory} 
      />)
    })
    grid.push(<Row key={i} columns={renderedRow} rowHeight={defaultDimensions * scale}/>)
  })

return (
   {grid}
)
```